# Geo Django get cities from latitude and longitude

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I'm learning how to use Geo Django. When a user registers I save the latitude and longitude information as seen below:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class GeoModel(models.Model):
    """
    Abstract model to provide GEO fields.
    """
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Latitude')
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Longitude')
    location = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.latitude and self.longitude:
            self.location = Point(float(self.latitude), float(self.longitude))
        super(GeoModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Next I want to add a new field called `city` where **I want to store the city "name" i.e. London based the long and lat details given.

I have looked at `django-cities` where is saves a database of cities from Geo Name, but this seems overkill and not Python 3 compatible so a no go for me. I have seen a package called [geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) but this seems to completely replace Geo Django and uses Google API which comes with restrictions.

I want to stick with **Geo Django** and somehow do a lookup to find out the City name based on long and lat so what are my options? i.e..

1. Find a way to install http://www.geonames.org/ data django-cities
   does not work for Python 3 and Django 1.8.x
2. Somehow use Geo Django
   to do this lookup using the data? (unsure ow to do this)

**Is above the correct way to approach this? If so how do I get the data into my DB then do a lookup on it using Geo Django to find the city name?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have several solutions to do this:

1. Create another model City

   ```
   from django.contrib.gis.db import models
   class City(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_lenght=255)
       geometry = models.MultiPolygonField()

       objects = models.GeoManager()
   ```

Then you can find the name of the city containing your location with:

```
    geomodel = GeoModel(...)
    city = City.objects.get(geometry__contains=geomodel.location)
    city_name = city.name
```

Depending on the country/region you are interested in, you may find city geometries to fill the City table in OpenData (eg http://www.gadm.org/country (not tested but seems to propose open shapefiles))

2. Use an inverse geocoder. Google can provide such service or look at http://www.geonames.org/export/reverse-geocoding.html if something can match your needs.

Comment: ``geomodel.location`` what sort of field is this ``PointField``?

Comment: Yes, this is the model you defined in your question :)

Comment: Last question so the ``MultiPolygonField`` used in the City model.  what is this how does it look? I decided to use Geo Name but it does not have that field http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=london&country=

Comment: MultiPolygonField contains the shape information for the city, such that the lookup `contains` check whether a point is inside a polygon. The shape doesn't seem to be present in http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt. 
Which country are you interested on ?

Comment: Try [here](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/geoportal/catalog/content/filelist.page?redirect=Docs/Boundaries/Counties_%28Eng%29_2008_Boundaries_%28Full_Extent%29.zip&pos=3) or [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain.html)